# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word how to stop the file opening

Tags: c#, io, ms-office, office-interop, com-interop

I have a bunch of word documents that I want to read and get their text value in a string.I am trying to to it by the **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word** with code looking similar to this one:

```
var wordApp = new Word.Application();
object file = fileName;
object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                           ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                           ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                           ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
doc.Close();
```

and at the: **Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open** line it prompts me for opening the file(with few options including:"Open a read only copy" etc.)
The Code works fine for me besides the fact that it opens the document.Is there any way just to get its content without opening it? I want my object to have the data loaded inside of it but I don't want to open the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
var wordApp = new Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = false;
```